# I am trying to play Among us cracked on Ubuntu 20.04 using wine but it doesn't work

Tags: wine, games

I watched a [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSa5uAqzQvE) about how to do this and followed the steps but I'm getting this error:

```
~/Downloads/Among.Us.v2021.3.5s/Among.Us.v2021.3.5s$ sudo wine Among\ Us.exe
000f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  0 ()


  Serial number of failed request:  227
  Current serial number in output stream:  227
```

I get the same error whether I use `sudo` or not.

Comment: I know Among Us is also availible on Steam. I also know you can download games on Linux using Lutris. Maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Co6FePZoNgE helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using virtual box to run it . It will be simple that way right?